# Rmarkdown parameters - not knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a problem knitting the following .Rmd file.

```
---
title: "parameter test"
output: html_document
parameters:
  data: "this is data"
---

`r params$data`
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in eval(parse_only(code), envir = envir):
object 'params' not found.
```

Can anyone point out to me my mistake please?

Comment: Your error is your answer. Where is object ```params```?

Comment: Thankyou manro. I am such a dummy. Need to be more aware when watching videos!

Answer (score 2):

Use `params`, not `parameters`:

```
---
title: "parameter test"
output: html_document
params:
  data: "this is data"
---

`r params$data`
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Stephane